# JHipster entity filtering code not being generated for the Gateway and a NON reactive microservice

Tags: microservices, jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I'm getting to grips with JHipster these days.
I'm using generator v7.2.0 and have the following in place and working:

- A non-reactive microservice with a few sample entities, based on a JDL file.
- JPA entity filtering generated for one of the entities, in the micro-service.
- A Vue based API Gateway (by default, reactive, as of recent JHipster versions).
- the other necessary "infrastructure", i.e. Registry, SQL databases etc.

In order to generate the entities UI in the gateway, I typically copy the `.jhipster` folder from the microservice to the gateway and do a `jhipster --with-entities` there, each time I have changes.

The CRUD pages work fine, complete with pagination and all, save for filtering, which is not generated at all, spitting out the `Not compatible with jpaMetamodelFiltering, disabling` message, which I can understand since the gateway is reactive, as shown in the below extract (lines 364-370) from the `entity` generator's `index.js`:

```
          this.entityConfig.jpaMetamodelFiltering &&
          (context.databaseType !== SQL || this.entityConfig.service === NO_SERVICE || context.reactive === true)
        ) {
          this.warning('Not compatible with jpaMetamodelFiltering, disabling');
          this.entityConfig.jpaMetamodelFiltering = false;
        }
```

The question is: Since my microservice is NOT reactive, and the UI would only be adding extra parameters to the REST calls for any filters and not doing any actual criteria queries on a local database, shouldn't code generation for the UI ignore the reactive check and spit the filters code out?

Many thanks in advance for any feedback provided.

Comment: Not sure Stackoverflow is the best place for this specific quesion. As you have identified the conditions that prevent from generating this gateway code, maybe you should try to disable them and see how it works. Then you could report it on github.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Yeah, you're probably right, I pondered on either posting a GitHub issue and/or try to tweak the generator myself, but thought I'd give it a quick go first, in case someone has a quick work-around.

Comment: Alright, I temporarily disabled the reactive check for gateways, only to realize that there is NO UI code for filters present at all, in the templates (at least not in the Vue/Angular ones)!

Facepalm moment!

Guess that means one would have to enhance the client entity generator to add the input filters in the HTML/VM/service etc layers....

Comment: Right, I forgot also about this, the fact is that it would require much work to do it only with Bootstrap while doing it with more advanced data table widget would be much easier.